"Invalid Subscription" error in QField
I am managing QField projects for an ecosystem restoration team. We are using QField to collect data, record progress, and help plan for future work-days. We have an organization account called "ReForest", (1.0 GB) set up with 2 other collaborators (all of whom are QFieldCloud Community Accounts) assigned to projects as Admins. (ReForest is the owner, plus myself and one other collaborator).
Everything was working great for a week or two.
Now, after no changes to anything we do (except the recrnt QField update to 3.3.1 Darien), we are getting the same errors when we try to Synchronize projects on QField:

And in the message log:

We are able to Push the changes to the cloud, though, so we've done this and I attempted to apply the changes in my web-browser from the QFieldCloud website itself, and this doesn't work either. I get these messages:

and

I am stumped as to why the subscription is invalid; we are only using 12% of our total storage, we are not using remote sensors or remote layers (as far as I know, Google Basemaps aren't remote layers), and there doesn't seem to be any information as to what specific features we are using that are not supported by our subscription, only suggestions.
Does this have anything to do with the latest QField update?
Or am I checking a checkbox somewhere by accident or some other user error?
How can I fix this?

Sounds like this bug https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues/4411 Which version of QField are you using?

I'm using QField v.3.3.1 Darien - brand new update.
That doesn't read like the issue I'm having; his error is saying to check device storage, my error is saying "invalid subscription" and this error doesn't happen with my personal QFieldCloud account, only on the Projects in the organization account, so from that I figure my device storage isn't the issue. Also, my issue is in the QField mobile app, not Desktop app, not sure if that makes a difference.

Could it possibly be that we signed up for a free trial and now the free trial is over?
If this is the case, where can we look to find this out?
